# 20.10: Complete system freeze with general protection fault (SMP NOPTI)

Tags: gnome, dell, freeze, 20.10

My Dell XPS 13 7390 running Ubuntu 20.10 (kernel 5.8.0-28-generic) regularly freezes up entirely.
This sometimes happens multiple times a day, sometimes every few days - I am unable to see a pattern here, nor figure out which apps or actions seem to provoke it.

When it happens:

1. The UI and keyboard freezes completely (including the clock in the GNOME menu bar), with only the mouse still being operable. I cannot click or interact with anything.
2. Alt + F2 does not react. Thus, I can neither `xkill` nor run a terminal from there.
3. Ctrl + Alt + F1 to start a new session also does not work.

I can only REISUB the computer to get it to restart, and I lose any unsaved work.

Upon restarting, having taken note of the time of the hang each time (the GNOME clock freezes at that exact time), `journalctl` delivers:

```
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0x7fc133498bf90874: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 1415 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 5.8.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 7390/0G2D0W, BIOS 1.5.1 03/09/2020
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RIP: 0010:kmem_cache_alloc+0x7e/0x230
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: Code: 95 01 00 00 4d 8b 07 65 49 8b 50 08 65 4c 03 05 a0 59 73 48 4d 8b 20 4d 85 e4 0f 84 81 01 00 00 41 8b 47 20 49 8b 3f 4c 01 e0 <48> 8b 18 48 89 c1 49 33 9f 70 01 00 00 4c 89 e0 48 0f c9 48 31 cb
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffa64201ceb9b0 EFLAGS: 00010216
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RAX: 7fc133498bf90874 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 0000000000000002
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RDX: 0000000000004d2f RSI: 0000000000000dc0 RDI: 00003460c14201e0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RBP: ffffa64201ceb9e0 R08: ffffc641ffc601e0 R09: 0000000000000000
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff91e112d0cffa R12: 7fc133498bf9071c
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: R13: 0000000000000dc0 R14: ffff91e1345a9dc0 R15: ffff91e1345a9dc0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: FS:  00007f57389c6a40(0000) GS:ffff91e13e840000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: CR2: 000001a9d0dfa000 CR3: 00000004589b6002 CR4: 00000000003606e0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: Call Trace:
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? vma_create+0x30/0x460 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  vma_create+0x30/0x460 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? mutex_lock+0x13/0x40
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  i915_vma_instance+0xd2/0xe0 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  eb_lookup_vma+0xd7/0x1c0 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  eb_lookup_vmas+0x79/0x200 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  eb_relocate+0x18/0x1b0 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  i915_gem_do_execbuffer+0x265/0x8d0 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? check_preempt_curr+0x84/0x90
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? ttwu_do_wakeup+0x1e/0x150
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? __radix_tree_replace+0x4a/0xe0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x168/0x240
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? __kmalloc_node+0x201/0x300
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  i915_gem_execbuffer2_ioctl+0x237/0x4a0 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? intel_engines_add_sysfs+0x150/0x150 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? radix_tree_lookup+0xd/0x10
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? i915_gem_execbuffer_ioctl+0x2e0/0x2e0 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x238/0x3d0 [drm]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? i915_gem_execbuffer_ioctl+0x2e0/0x2e0 [i915]
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? fput+0x13/0x15
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ? __sys_recvmsg+0x94/0xb0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  ksys_ioctl+0x8e/0xc0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x49/0xc0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f5738e2b31b
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: Code: 89 d8 49 8d 3c 1c 48 f7 d8 49 39 c4 72 b5 e8 1c ff ff ff 85 c0 78 ba 4c 89 e0 5b 5d 41 5c c3 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 1d 3b 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffd240f9788 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000557e494b8a50 RCX: 00007f5738e2b31b
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RDX: 00007ffd240f97b0 RSI: 0000000040406469 RDI: 000000000000000e
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: RBP: 00007f5736bd6000 R08: 0000000000003fd0 R09: 00007f5735e10000
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: R10: 00007f5712520000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007ffd240f97b0
Nov 20 16:42:25 flo-xps-13 kernel: R13: 000000000000000e R14: 000000000000012a R15: 0000000000001000
```

The offending PID `1415` belongs to `gdm-x-session`, as seen by another log entry:

```
Nov 20 16:17:37 flo-xps-13 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1415]: (EE) event12 - CUST0001:00 06CB:76B1 Touchpad: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 15ms, your system is too slow
```

I cannot find any meaningful help online.

Helpful information may also include:

- It's a dual boot system with Windows 10.
- I run with fractional scaling enabled (dconf `org/gnome/mutter/x11/experimental-features` set to `[scale-monitor-framebuffer, x11-randr-fractional-scaling]`).

As I was often using JetBrains IDEs when the freezes happened, [I ran across this YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1644?_ga=2.264754503.933087481.1605888178-1556007611.1604932995&_gac=1.192827992.1604941596.Cj0KCQiA7qP9BRCLARIsABDaZzjC5Y8x1ZKpvOwV_y6tgJuDM0tpbJCu7QzWg1VD2WwnC1uE4tlhP20aAg39EALw_wcB), detailing a downgrade of mutter would solve a similar issue on Ubuntu 19.10 - however, I don't know how to adapt this to my specific issue.

Comment: Is [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1901563) related? Drilling down, it suggests that the issue was fixed by at least kernel 5.9.3. I would suggest you try the mainline kernel, just for a test, say [5.10-rc4](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10-rc4/).

Comment: @DougSmythies This definitely seems very similar - thank you. I will try the mainline kernel and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `gdm-x-session` bug in `journalctl` every time it freeze ?

If not, try updating the **kernel** to the latest version possible. If you have `secure boot` enabled, you will probably need to **disable it** to update kernel, or **sign it** on your own ([see this](https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2020/08/19/secure-boot-signing-kernel-files-in-ubuntu/)).

I've got same issue on my fresh new laptop Dell Latitude 7420 running Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with Windows 10. In my case it mostly freeze when the laptop was hot, often when being on AC. It also ran fans too loud, even if the temperature only got 5°C higher than at idle. I disabled `secure boot` and updated kernel `5.11.16` (as it was latest version I could update to due to dependencies) and it definitely helped - no problem since then.

Comment: I have actually not been able to report back on this since the bug seems to have disappeared for me on GNOME 3.38.3, kernel 5.8.0-53.